# GCP - TPU training gets too slow with data augmentation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-cloud-ml, tpu

After adding a few augmentation techniques like random brightness, contrast, jitter boxes my model training has become too slow on V3-8 TPUs.

Examples per sec dropped from around 220 to 20.